# Excel MAX/MIN but only if opposing cell is greater than 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, conditional-statements

I've found similar examples through searching but I can't find anything that matches the issue that I have...

I have a table which shows parts received/rejected, I wish to see the maximum days early/late (I'll only need help with one as the other I can then do!) 
- but there are dummy orders which I wish to ignore (they show a received/reject of 0).

Here is example data from the 'AnnualDump' sheet:

[image: Table]

My current calculation is

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AnnualDump!$H$2),"BLANK",0-MIN(AnnualDump!$G:$G))
```

[Column H is Received/Rejected and G is VarianceDays]

This simply looks at if there is any data on the sheet before running the calculation, which is fantastic for 95% of the time... but I want to ignore any values that have a received/rejected of 0...

I want it to show 29, but it's showing 30 in this instance as it's not ignoring 0qty lines.
I've tried adding another IF statement but it didn't work :/

Completely stuck now and not sure what the next step to try is...
I can do it if I cheat *(call both columns to another sheet, turn text white, use an 'IF cell greater than x, then value' to compare the whole lot and then min/max that third column)* but I'm trying to avoid that!

Any pointers or help will be greatly appreciated (complete VBA noob in excel so I'd like to avoid that if possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this array formula. Confirm with Ctrl, Shift and Enter and curly brackets will appear round the formula.

I would strongly suggest you don't use full column references though as these formulae are rather resource-intensive.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(AnnualDump!$H$2),"BLANK",0-MIN(IF(AnnualDump!$H:$H>0,AnnualDump!$G:$G)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. What would you recommend in place of full columns? Annoyingly until it's put into practice more I do not know the length of the data but I could limit it to $H$2:$H$999 or something like that? Doubt it would be near 1000 lines but it gives me some space.

Comment: Actually it looks like you are using a table so reference that and it will automatically adjust as your data expands.

Comment: Excellent, I'll do that, thanks for the help. My original idea with the additional IF looked similar but I didn't know about the CTRL+SHIFT entry... every day's a school day!

Comment: i.e. it would look something along the lines of `=MIN(IF(Table1[Heading 2]>0,Table1[Heading 1]))`